# Call knockout viewmodel function from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, knockout.js

I know there are several similar questions like this already, but none of them helped solved my problem.

I'm trying to upload a file using ajax post and return a json containing the file description which is then passed to a knockout viewmodel function which is inside my .js file.

I can upload the files using ajax post:

```
     $('.upload-button').click(function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0];
        formData.append("FileUpload", file);
        var action = "/QuestionWizard/Upload";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                //call viewmodel function here and pass result
            }
        });
    });
```

this is my viewmodel function:

```
      var ViewModel = function (d, m) {
        var self = this;
        var formData = null;

        self.Model = ko.mapping.fromJS(d, m);



        self.AddDoc = function (data) {
            self.Model.CurrentStep().Files.push({ Name: data.Name, Extension: data.Extension, ContentType: data.ContentType, Size: data.Size, Content: data.Content, FilePath: data.FilePath, Folder: data.Folder });
        }

    }
```

Upload Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Upload() {
        FileUploadModel upload = new FileUploadModel();

        try {

            if (Request.Files != null) {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                upload.Size = settings.ConvertBytesToMegabytes(file.ContentLength);

                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream)) {
                    upload.Content = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
                }

                upload.Name = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName);
                upload.ContentType = Request.Files[0].ContentType;
                upload.Extension = Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName);
                upload.Folder = User.Question + "-" + User.Token;
                Transmit.write(ref upload);
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            return Json(null);
        }
        return Json(upload);
    }
```

Upload Button in view:

```
 <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" data-bind="event:{ change: Upload.bind($data, $element.files[0]) }" />
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to call  the viewmodel function and pass the resulting json or a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move your AJAX into a scope where the view model is present. For example, I typically structure my Knockout code like:

```
var Namespace = Namespace || {};

Namespace.AppName = (function () {
    var _init = function (data) {
        var viewModel = Namespace.AppName.ViewModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        _wireEvents(viewModel);
    };

    var _wireEvents = function (viewModel) {
        // using the example of your AJAX method
        $('.upload-button').click(viewModel.DoUpload);
    };

    return {
        Init: _init
    };
})();
```

Then, to wire everything up, you just need to do something like the following in your view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = {}; // any initial data you feed into the view model
    Namespace.AppName.Init(data);
});
```

Since the `.upload-button` click handler actually calls a method on your view model, you have direct access to it. For example, inside your view model definition:

```
self.DoUpload = function () {
    ...

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            // use `self` to access any view model observable
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: `$('.upload-button')` inside the controller isn't what I'd think of as best practices... better to create a function on the VM and `data-bind` that to the click event of the button, no?

Comment: Not at all. This uses Knockout's support for unobtrusive event handling. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html.

Comment: Okay, they support it, sure. But mixing and matching... seems a bit of a smell to me.  Anyhow, thanks.